# I'm trying to print whole value of "fields." But it skips the first input, why?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class elseif {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter name");
            String a = s.next();
            System.out.println("Enter roll number");
            int b = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Filed of interest");
            s.next();//To consume '\n' left by ENTER KEY, it is not consumed by nextInt()
            String c = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Hey, my name is "+a+" and my roll number is "+b+". 
                                My field of interest is "+c+".");
          }
        }
```

Output:

```
Enter name
Subhadip
Enter roll number
21
Enter Filed of interest
music, dance
Hey, my name is Subhadip and my roll number is 21. My field of interest is dance.
```

It doesn't print "music."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `s.next();` you can use `Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());` to get `b`

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter name");
String a = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter roll number");
int b = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter Filed of interest");
String c = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hey, my name is "+a+" and my roll number is "+b+". My field of interest is "+c+".");
```